# How to make indent for groups in Xceed datagrid?

Tags: wpf, grouping, xceed, xceed-datagrid

The Xceed datagrid provides drag and Drop option to group data by any column.
But the level of indent for all groups is by default made zero. 
How to provide proper indent for the groups.
For Eg:

```
ParentGroup_Level1

    ChildGroup_Level2

        ChildGroup_Level3

            Data

            Data

    ChildGroup_Level2

        ChildGroup_Level3

            Data

            Data
```

Should I modify the Datagrid's template? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Xceed TableflowView can do this by default:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
                        <xcdg:TableflowView AreGroupsFlattened="False">
```

May be paid version only.

Comment: Ya, the free version didn't have any effect on adding this. Thanks for your response.